# How to delete the order Items from magento using Rest API

Tags: magento2, orders, rest-api, delete, order-items

I want to delete the order Item form the Successfully placed Order how to delete the order item.Can anyone help to solve this situation.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, **Magento2** does not have any API point for the delete an order item.

But PHP function `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface::delete(\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface $entity)`  exits which can delete the order item. You can  create custom API point using webapi.xml and call this method on delete operation.

As per the Magento 2 system, order item delete does not a good idea. you can issue orders  shipment, invoice  etc.

Comment: Thanks @amitBera